# Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

I have a .NET 2.0 project and I get the following error when I try to compile some projects that use SMO:

> The primary reference "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0".
>
> To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

Can someone help. I don't want to move the projects to .NET 3.5 because of this.

Thanks

Comment: [Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/651546/microsoft-sqlserver-smo-could-not-be-resolved-because-it-has-an-indirect-dependency-on-the-framework-assembly-system-core-version-3-5-0-0)

Comment: You may be out of luck.  The error message basically states that .NET 3.5 is required.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/e77bcdb0-d0d2-4f57-a1ce-642b686c8530/

Comment: You might try loading one of the older versions of SMO.

Comment: [You can download an earlier version of SMO (2005) here...](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15748)

Comment: But, why should I change the .NET version of my projects? It used to compile under .NET version 2.0... I didn't break that piece of code...

Comment: You're not being asked to change the .NET version.  You're being asked to use an older version of SMO that's compatible with .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: What functionality of SMO are you using? The SMO have proven to be problematic in different ways when deployed with your own applications (native code is used for the parser component for instance, so that no XCOPY deployment is possible etc.), so you may be able to find the required functionality in other libraries or by issuing some SQL commands directly.

Comment: The dll that I use has Runtime Version = v2.0.50727. It is build as a .NET 2.0 assembly. It was compatible and I didn't have any problems, until, I guess, I installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1... I wouldn't post the question if this wasn't the case.

Comment: Note: Framework 2, 3 and 3.5 are ALL built on top of the CLR 2.

Answer (score 0):

As the exceptions says the current reference assembly needs .NET 3.5. You must downgrade Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo which support .NET 2.0.